# Computing truncated signed distance function(TSDF) from a point cloud

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, point-clouds

I'm trying to implement in matlab a function to compute the truncated  signed distance function in order to render a volumetric model from a point cloud using something like the method described in [this article](https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/volrange/volrange.pdf). Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo can find a reference implementation here:

https://github.com/andyzeng/3dmatch-toolbox/blob/master/README.md#converting-3d-data-to-tdf-voxel-grids

The matlab-only implementation is on this file:
https://github.com/andyzeng/3dmatch-toolbox/blob/master/evaluation/model-fitting-apc/pointCloud2TDF.m

Comment: @Wael Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted